# Formatting issue with DateTime diff

Tags: php, database, datetime

I am trying to find the difference in days between two dates using DateTime. I understand that there are several other posts explaining how to do this. However, I receive an error when my code is run. I think this may be a formatting issue but I am at a loss.

As you can see I have tried to format $orderdate to the Y-m-d format recommended in the docs. It seems to be doing the trick. Am I missing something? According to the docs this should be working.

```
$orderdate = strip_tags(str_replace(array('"', "'"), "", str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $_POST['pickupship-date'])));
$orderdate = $conn->real_escape_string($orderdate);
$orderdate = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($orderdate) );
echo $orderdate;

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$completiondate = date("m/d/Y");
$completiondate = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($completiondate) );
echo $completiondate;

$duration = $orderdate->diff($completiondate);
$duration->format('%R%a days');
echo $duration;
```

EDIT: I have updated the code based on suggestions I have received. echo $orderdate and echo $completiondate are outputting exactly as expected. However, I get nothing for $duration.

Comment: Can you show a sample data and the expected output ?

Comment: What is your `$_POST` data - please do something like this: `echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, TRUE) . '</pre>';`

Comment: Also this looks very complicated - `$orderdate = strip_tags(str_replace(array('"', "'"), "", str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $_POST['pickupship-date'])));` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Here is the post data:' [pickupship-date] => 01/09/2019' After the date_format echoing the variable looks like: 2019-01-09. The complicated part just strips quotes and line breaks from the post data.

Comment: Okay so is that `dd/mm/yyyy` format, or `mm/dd/yyyy`? Also I would look at the `strtotime()` function in PHP -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: @ShaunBebbers it is mm/dd/yyyy. Thanks for the suggestion on strtotime(). Please see my edit.

Comment: `$orderdate = date(...)` puts a string in `$orderdate`. Several lines below, `$orderdate->diff()` produces a fatal error.

Comment: @axiac Thanks for the explanation. That makes sense. What would you suggest to ensure that this will work? My understanding was that strtotime() would handle this.

Comment: If you need to handle timezones, stay away from the old date & time functions and use only the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class (and [its friends](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)). If you don't need to handle timezones, do the same. It's 2019, not 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what do you want to achieve with this code. Most of what it does is incorrect or not needed.

> ```
> $orderdate = strip_tags(str_replace(array('"', "'"), "", str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $_POST['pickupship-date'])));
> ```

You should impose a fixed format for the `pickupship-date` field. Something like `Y-m-d` (or `m/d/Y` if you prefer it more) and stick with it. It doesn't make any sense to have quotes, apostrophes, newlines or HTML tags in a date-time field. If the input value doesn't match the expected format then display an error and stop the processing here.

> ```
> $orderdate = $conn->real_escape_string($orderdate);
> ```

Use a DB string escaping function only with the data you use to build an SQL query. This operation does not make any sense for the operations you do below with `$orderdate`.
You should use prepared SQL queries to protect the application from SQL injection, not arbitrary escaping and query building by joining strings, anyway.

> ```
> $completiondate = date("m/d/Y");
> $completiondate = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($completiondate) );
> ```

[`date("m/d/Y")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) formats the current date & time as string using the `m/d/Y` format.
[`strtotime($completionDate)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does the reverse; it tries to parse the just-generated string back into the current time and returns number (the number of seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`).

Then, `date("Y-m-d", ...)` produces another text representation of the just-parsed date & time. All in all, these two lines do the same as `$completiondate = date('Y-m-d');`

> ```
> $duration = $orderdate->diff($completiondate);
> ```

This is completely wrong. `$orderdate` is a string, it does not have the `diff()` method (it does not have any method, a string is not an object in PHP).
More, [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) expects another `DateTime` object as argument.

> ```
> $duration->format('%R%a days');
> ```

This line is correct (but it works only if `$duration` is properly created and this doesn't happen now).

### How your code should look like.

Because it's 2019 and not 2009, you should stay away from the old [date & time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) (they don't know how to handle the timezones and they are awkward anyway) and use only the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class (and [its friends](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)).

The code you need could look like this:

```
// The timezone
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago');

// Parse the input value, get a DateTime object back, or FALSE on error
$orderDate = date_create($_POST['pickupship-date'], $tz);
if (! $orderDate) {
  // The input value does not look like a valid date
  // Display an error, stop the processing here
  // ...
}

// Get the current date & time
$processingDate = new DateTime('now', $tz);

// Compute the difference
$duration = $orderdate->diff($completionDate);

// Format the difference for display
$duration->format('%R%a days')
```

#### Remarks

The call:

```
date_create($_POST['pickupship-date'], $tz)
```

is almost the same as:

```
new DateTime($_POST['pickupship-date'], $tz)
```

but it returns `FALSE` if the input value is not valid.
There is no way to get a value that signals an invalid input using `new`.

The code looks cleaner when you use `new DateTime()` but it works as expected only if you have already validated (by other means) the value you pass to it. If the input string is not a valid date, the new `DateTime` object is initialized with `1970-01-01 00:00:00` or with another value you don't want/expect.

[`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) prevents this by returning `FALSE` when the input string is not a valid date & time.

Both ways accept [multiple formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for the argument, including partial date & time representations and almost any English textual datetime description (f.e. `'yesterday noon'`).

If you want to use a fixed format for the input string you can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).
It uses an additional parameter (the first one) that is a format string (in the format accepted by [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) or [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)) and returns a `DateTime` object only if the input string matches the provided format (and `FALSE` otherwise).

Comment: I totally agree with you. Your approach is much better than the one I was taking. As such I have marked it as the answer. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that ended up working for me:

```
$orderdate = strip_tags(str_replace(array('"', "'"), "", str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $_POST['pickupship-date'])));
$orderdate = $conn->real_escape_string($orderdate);

$completiondate = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
$completiondate = $completiondate->format('Y-m-d');

$orderdate = new DateTime($orderdate);
$completiondate = new DateTime($completiondate);
$duration = $orderdate->diff($completiondate);
$duration = $duration->format('%R%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your life simple and use the DateTime Class which will do a lot of things for you.
important: the date() function returns a string, not some Date Object.
So

```
$orderdate = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($orderdate) );
$orderdate->diff
```

diffs strings and not the thing you want.

```
<?php
$_POST['pickupship-date'] = "2018-03-04";
$replaceNewLines = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), ' ', $_POST['pickupship-date']);
//not necessary when you use prepared statements. Always use prepared statements!!!
// $replaceQuotes = str_replace(array('"', "'"), "", $replaceNewLines);
$orderdate = strip_tags($replaceNewLines);
//always use prepared statements, then you don't have to do this
//$orderdate = $conn->real_escape_string($orderdate);
// strtotime not necessary $orderdate = date( "Y-m-d ", strtotime($orderdate) );
$orderdate = new DateTime($orderdate);
echo '$orderdate :';
var_dump($orderdate->format("Y-m-d"));

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$completiondate = new DateTime();
echo '$completiondate :';
var_dump( $completiondate->format("Y-m-d"));

$duration = $orderdate->diff($completiondate);
echo '$duration :';
var_dump($duration->format('%d days'));
```